# How to format Excel file output in R

Tags: r, excel

I'm writing a code that reads a CSV file, and generates two XLSX files, depending if the sites needed updates and where the location is. For example I would have sample data such as:

[image: Data example 1]

And the issue I'm having now, is that I want to apply Excel table style "Olive Green, Table Style Medium 18". I have an option where I have to pass a workbook, but since I'm not directly creating a workbook but rather reading a CSV file, how would I continue this?

Right now, I'm just using `write.xlsx()` to export my data to Excel, but I would like to apply a formatting to the table.

Sample code:

```
#Determine the input and output parameters 
input_file <-  choose.files()
output_eu <- "eu.xlsx"
output_noteu <- "noteu.xlsx"

#list of EU countries 
eu <- c("Andorra","Austria","Belarus","Belgium","Bosnia and Herzegovina","Bulgaria","Croatia","Czech Republic","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","France","Germany","Greece","Hungary","Iceland","Ireland","Italy","Latvia","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Malta","Moldova","Monaco","Montenegro","Netherlands","Norway","Poland","Portugal","Romania","Russia","San Marino","Serbia","Slovakia","Slovenia","Spain","Sweden","Switzerland","Ukraine","United Kingdom")

#reading the csv table
d <- read.table(input_file, sep = ";", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE) 

# get all cases where there is some text in the Update field
updates <- d[d$Update != "", ]

#within updates are there countries in EU
i <- updates$Country %in% eu

eu_up <- updates[i,]
noteu_up <- updates[!i,]

#Creating the excel files 
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(eu_up, output_eu) 
write.xlsx(noteu_up, output_noteu)
```

Update1: Added the sample code to show that I use 1 CSV file that goes into two excel files.

Updated Code:

```
#Determine the input and output parameters 
input_file <-  choose.files()
output_eu <- "eu.xlsx"
output_noteu <- "noteu.xlsx"

#list of EU countries 
eu <- c("Andorra","Austria","Belarus","Belgium","Bosnia and Herzegovina","Bulgaria","Croatia","Czech Republic","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","France","Germany","Greece","Hungary","Iceland","Ireland","Italy","Latvia","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Malta","Moldova","Monaco","Montenegro","Netherlands","Norway","Poland","Portugal","Romania","Russia","San Marino","Serbia","Slovakia","Slovenia","Spain","Sweden","Switzerland","Ukraine","United Kingdom")

#reading the csv table
d <- read.table(input_file, sep = ";", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE) 

# get all cases where there is some text in the Update field
updates <- d[d$Update != "", ]

#within updates are there countries in EU
i <- updates$Country %in% eu

eu_up <- updates[i,]
noteu_up <- updates[!i,]


#importing openxlsx library 
library(openxlsx)

#create the workbook for each one 
wb_eu <- createWorkbook()
wb_xeu <-createWorkbook()

#adding the data to each corresponding workbook 
addWorksheet(wb_eu, "European Sites") 
addWorksheet(wb_xeu, "Non-European Sites")

#write our tables into each 
writeDataTable(wb_eu, 1, eu_up, startRow=1, startCol=1, tableStyle="TableStyleLight11")
writeDataTable(wb_xeu, 1,  noteu_up, startRow=1, startCol=1, tableStyle="TableStyleLight11")

#setting our column widths 
setColWidths(wb_eu, 1, cols=1:26, widths = "auto") 
setColWidths(wb_xeu, 1, cols=1:26, widths = "auto") 

#saving our workbooks 
saveWorkbook(wb_eu, "European Sites updated.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE) 
saveWorkbook(wb_xeu, "Non-European Sites updated.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hello, please avoid uploading pictures of your data and instead upload a small sample of it. Also we will need to see your code in order to test it out. Try editing this question with a reproducible example that contains a small sample of your data.

Comment: read community guidelines and please post reproducible example...u r question nice but the way u r asking is something. so please avoid attaching or posting images in the question

Comment: There are several options. Some years ago, I have decided to use the `xlsx` package to create nicely formatted Excel file output. An alternative might be the `openxlsx` package which might have matured in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`library(openxlsx)` works well for this.

```
library(openxlsx)
```

First you need to create a workbook:

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
```

Then add two worksheets to it:

```
addWorksheet(wb, "EU")
addWorksheet(wb, "NOTEU")
```

Then let's write our two tables:

```
writeDataTable(wb, 1, eu_up, startRow = 1, startCol = 1, tableStyle = "TableStyleMedium18")
writeDataTable(wb, 2, noteu_up, startRow = 1, startCol = 1, tableStyle = "TableStyleMedium18")

saveWorkbook(wb, "Tables_with_Formatting.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you!! It's working now that I added the createWorkbook(), I added an updated code to reflect what I've done!

Comment: Great, you can click the check mark indicating this answer solved your problem, assuming it has.